# Get row item instead of index-# from iterrows()

Tags: python, pandas

I am new in Python, and trying to understand how the iterrows-function works in Pandas. I am trying to iterate over each row in the csv-file below and print the values in the name, month and day-columns. It works for all except for the name-column. Index-numbers are printed instead of "Brond" and "Birdie".

```
### Below is the content of a file named examples.csv:
name,email,year,month,day
Brond,example1@email.com,1985,09,30
Birdie,example2@email.com,1985,08,29
```

My attempt is:

```
with open("examples.csv") as examples_file:
examples = pandas.read_csv(examples_file)
for (index, row) in examples.iterrows():
    print(row.name)

### The printed result is "0" and "1", instead of "Brond" and "Birdie".
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should avoid using the attributes (`row.name`) and rather slice with indices (`row['name']`).

Using attributes has many pitfalls, you just fell in one! `.name` gives the Series name so if an indices name clashes, this doesn't work.

```
for (index, row) in examples.iterrows():
    print(row['name'])
```

output:

```
Brond
Birdie
```